# Pandas. Selecting specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a Dataframe with many columns `Name,Sex, Age, Education, Race`. I want to create a DF only with the following columns `Age,Sex,Educaion`.
I know that I can do it with the following method.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[['Age','Sex','Education']]
```

Is there a way  to do something like this. i.e Select all columns excepth x, y, z.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df(select all columns except the following columns = 'Race', 'Name'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) from pandas

Example:
`df.drop(columns=[list_of_columns_to_drop])`